# Angular 6 - ng-bootstrap - Add custom data attribute on the tab level

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-components, ng-bootstrap

I created the following structure using ng-boostrap:

```
<ngb-tabset>
    <ngb-tab title="Tab 1">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
            Tab 1
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
    <ngb-tab title="Tab 2">
        <ng-template ngbTabContent>
            Tab 2
        </ng-template>
    </ngb-tab>
</ngb-tabset>
```

I need to add a custom data attribute to the "li" or "a" elements which are generated by this template. Something like:

```
<li data-test="test">
    <a></a>
</li>
```

Any idea if I can do this?

Comment: I don't think you can, as the purpose of such libraries is to abstract those kind of things. Maybe try with a custom directive searching for a `li` in your tab ? Something like `<ngb-tab addCustomAttribute="my-custom-attribute" title="Tab 1">`

Comment: @trichetriche, maybe you can add a answer with your solution?

Comment: I'm not coding for you ... Try it and if you encounter an issue, I'll be there !

Comment: @trichetrichem, I just wanted to mark you answer as the correct one, lol

Comment: Don't you worry about that, I have enough reputation, simply try it, and if you have an issue with it, create another question and if you want to, notify me from this question so that I can help you !

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```html
<ngb-tab>
    <ng-template ngbTabTitle>Tab 1</ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>Text 1
    </ng-template>
</ngb-tab>
<ngb-tab>
    <ng-template ngbTabTitle>Tab 2</ng-template>
    <ng-template ngbTabContent>Text 2
    </ng-template>
</ngb-tab>
```

Comment: Where is the data attribute?